# Factory Pattern with Identity 2.0 and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We are developing a Full Stack Authorised WebApi with Entity Framework and Identity 2.0.

Its based on a git repo here

[WebApi Full Stack Entity Framework Repository](https://github.com/carbonrobot/FullStackEF)

In our service layer we pass across the a custom interface from our context i.e.

```
    private readonly Func<IGPFocusDataContext> _contextFactory;

    public PatientService(Func<IGPFocusDataContext> contextFactory)
    {
        this._contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }
```

I've created a similar UserService, its at this point I want to inject the UserManager and RoleManager interface in a similar way.

Can anyone recommend the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the repo you can add the instances/implementations of UserManger and RoleManager to the Unity container in UnityConfig.cs something like:

```
container.RegisterType<UserManager, UserManager>();
```

Or

```
container.RegisterType<IUserManager, UserManager>();
```

And then in your UserService

```
private readonly IUserManger _userManger;
private readonly IRoleManger _roleManger;

public UserService(IUserManger userManger, IRoleManager roleManger)
{
    this._userManager = userManger;
    this._roleManger = roleManger;
}
```

When you add the service in your controller similar to the PatientService in PatientsController, although I am not familiair with Unity, I expect Unity ties it all together.